# Add trailing slash to all URLs by default for Django App deployed on Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, django, ssl, heroku

I have a Django App deployed on Heroku. When running the app locally, all the URLs are automatically appended with trailing slash. However, on deploying the app to heroku, the URLs do not add the trailing slash and this causes 404 error. In the `settings.py` file for the Django project, `'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'` is set.

Is there a way to ensure that all URLs automatically add "/" even on heroku?

Comment: Tried `APPEND_SLASH = True`? in settings.py